# USB Mass Storage device detected but no /dev/sdX?

Tags: linux, mount, usb, external-hdd

I have a HDD that want to mount using a USB+power cable. When connecting, I see the message:

```
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621, bcdDevice= 0.36
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 20211228
usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
```

However, `lsblk`, `dmesg` and `journalctl -f` shows no device matching `/dev/sd*` assigned to it.

How can I mount it then? Fedora 38 fully updated.

Comment: `ls -ld /dev/sd*` returns only the internal SSD. I don't see anywhere the external HDD.

Comment: Do a few new messages arrive a couple seconds later in dmesg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are providing external power to the storage device. There's [a post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=75600) relating to `1f75:0621` and a Pi that notes this as an issue.

[Another suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/q/698969/473234) is to use a USB2 cable, and/or to ensure that you're using a [USB2 port](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1332722) on the computer rather than USB3.

This [final comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1332722/comments/23) clearly points the finger at the Innostor enclosure itself.

Comment: Yes, the adapter has a power supply, and the HDD is spinning.

I tried all the USB ports in my computer (2 USB2, 4 USB3) and only worked once...

Comment: I am using the USB cable that came with the adapter. Probably USB3.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit looks like it's the enclosure. Answer updated

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisA.Florit please what's the solution? I have exact same problem. Dmesg stops at ```usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 1-2:1.0```. I don't know what that 'enclosure' is about

Comment: @Mab that line is no use without the previous few, like in the question.

Comment: @Mab The solution was very technical and tricky: to through the thing in the trash bin and buy another one. The enclosure was sh*t.